# batch file replace characters in file

Tags: windows, batch-file

It's been a while since I wrote a batch file. I used to play with it back in the day, but now I need to write one, and I'm lost. Can anyone give me a hand? I need to write a batch file with the following requirements:

- It will be run in Windows
- It should take a filename as the only parameter
- It should search only the first 100 characters in the file and should replace the occurrence of two consecutive asterisks `**` with one asterisk, two spaces, and a final asterisk `*  *`

  - OLD: `The quick brown f**ox jumped over something`
  - NEW: `The quick brown f*  *ox jumped over something`
- The new version of the file should be saved as the original filename plus .new to a subfolder

  - original filename `C:\Myfolder\myfile.txt`
  - new filename `C:\Myfolder\NewFolder\myfile.txt.new`

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. install cygwin. 2. use sed/awk

Comment: If you need to do this with multiple files, why not just use a tool like Notepad++ / Eclipse / some other multi-file text editor to do a search and replace...?

Comment: I'm not able to run cygwin, since the batch file will be called from within another Windows application.

Answer (score 0):

Use a native port of `sed`.

GnuWin32 includes one: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

So does the windows port of Git.

The following assumes you are using ASCII text files: 100 bytes == 100 characters.

```
@echo off
set output_file=%input_file%.new
set end_of_header=5
set /a start_of_body=%end_of_header% + 1

head --bytes=%end_of_header% ^
    %input_file% ^
    | sed --expression "s/\*\*/*  */g" ^
    1> %output_file%

tail --bytes=+%start_of_body% ^
    %input_file% ^
    1>> %output_file%

type %input_file% %output_file%
```